# Select texts between tags in Xpath in Python

Tags: python, xpath

```html
<td width="250">
10.03.1984 16:30
<br/>
Lütfi Kırdar, İstanbul
<br/>
<br/>
47-38, 49-58, 8-10
</td>
```

I want to get all text between "td" tags. My code is mactarih=tree.xpath("//tr//td[@width='250']//text()") . But it is wrong.

The expected result is:
text=['10.03.1984 16:30','Lütfi Kırdar, İstanbul','47-38, 49-58, 8-10']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"My code is `mactarih=tree.xpath("//tr//td[@width='250']//text()")`. But it is wrong"*.

If it was 'wrong' in the sense that it returned empty texts or newlines along with the correct texts, then you can use `normalize-space()` to filter out whitespace-only texts :

```
mactarih=tree.xpath("//tr//td[@width='250']//text()[normalize-space()]")
```

Quick test :

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> raw = '''<td width="250">
... 10.03.1984 16:30
... <br/>
... Lütfi Kırdar, İstanbul
... <br/>
... <br/>
... 47-38, 49-58, 8-10
... </td>'''
>>> root = etree.fromstring(raw)
>>> root.xpath("//td[@width='250']//text()[normalize-space()]")
['\n10.03.1984 16:30\n', u'\nL\xfctfi K\u0131rdar, \u0130stanbul\n', '\n47-38, 49-58, 8-10\n']
```